# Why does java throw the Parameter index out of range SQLerror

Tags: java, mysql, sql, bukkit, sqlexception

I've been running this code multiple times and java keeps throwing the java.sql.SQLException Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters which is 0), I think it bugs on the SELECT * FROM `CARD` query, what am I doing wrong here?

```
@EventHandler
public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event){
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    openConnection();
    try{
        PreparedStatement sql = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `Cards` WHERE `UUID`=?;");
        sql.setString(1, player.getUniqueId().toString());
        ResultSet rs = sql.executeQuery();
        if(!rs.next()){
            PreparedStatement sql1 = connection.prepareStatement("INSET INTO `Cards` (`UUID`, `username`, `name`, `race`, `tribe`, `gender`, age`, `desc`, `channel`, `ooc`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");
            sql1.setString(1, player.getUniqueId().toString());
            sql1.setString(2, player.getName());
            sql1.setString(3, "NONE");
            sql1.setString(4, "NONE");
            sql1.setString(5, "NONE");
            sql1.setString(6, "NONE");
            sql1.setString(7, "0");
            sql1.setString(8, "NONE");
            sql1.setString(9, "RP");
            sql1.setString(10, "1");
            sql1.execute();
            sql1.close();
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        closeConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: *Where* is it throwing the exception? You've got two SQL statements - only one of them is likely to be relevant here. You shouldn't "think it bugs on" - you should have a stack trace. You should be able to write a method which demonstrates this in a minimal way - given that we'd need a schema, it's unlikely that it'll be a short but complete program, but you can at least nail it down further than you have here.

Comment: Next problem: INSET != INSERT.

Comment: You dont read from your ResultSet...

Comment: The problem was the misspell of INSERT, it's fixed now, and I use the resultset to check if the user already exists with rs.next();

Answer (score 5):

```
(`UUID`, `username`, `name`, `race`, `tribe`, `gender`, age`, `desc`, `channel
```

Missing quotes on `age`?

Comment: How about just removing all those unnecessary quotes altogether